# Delphi - Help calling threaded dll function from another thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, dll, synchronize

I'm using Delphi 2006 and have a bit of a problem with an application I'm developing.

I have a form that creates a thread which calls a function that performs a lengthy operation, lets call it LengthyProcess. Inside the LengthyProcess function we also call several Dll functions which also create threads of their own.

The problem that I am having is that if I don't use the Synchronize function of my thread to call LengthyProcess the thread stops responding (the main thread is still responding fine).  I don't want to use Synchronize because that means the main thread is waiting for LengthyProcess to finish and therefore defeats the purpose of creating a separate thread.

I have tracked the problem down to a function inside the dll that creates a thread and then calls WaitFor, this is all done using TThread by the way.  WaitFor checks to see if the CurrentThreadID is equal to the MainThreadID and if it is then it will call CheckSychronization, and all is fine. So if we use Synchronize then the CurrentThreadID will equal the MainThreadID however if we do not use Synchronize then of course CurrentThreadID <> MainThreadID, and when this happens WaitFor tells the current thread (the thread I created) to wait for the thread created by the DLL and so CheckSynchronization never gets called and my thread ends up waiting forever for the thread created in the dll.

I hope this makes sense, sorry I don't know any better way to explain it.  Has anyone else had this issue and knows how to solve it please?

Comment: Your redaction is confusing me.  Can you clarify which WaitFor the dll calls?  Sounds to me like the function, executing in the context of the 2nd. thread calls WaitFor for the same 2nd. thread.

Answer (score 7):

If your secondary thread "stops responding," then I assume it has a message pump. (Otherwise, you need to explain what it stops responding *to*.) You appear to also wish for the thread to be able to detect when the tertiary thread finishes running. (The "primary" thread here is the VCL thread, which isn't involved at all.)

You tried using `WaitFor`, but were disappointed when you discovered that it blocks. That's what it has always been designed to do, though. Its behavior in the main thread is where it gets weird, so it's safe to call from the VCL thread even though it was never really meant to be used that way originally.

To process messages *and* wait for threads to finish running, you need to use one or more of the [wait functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069.aspx) from the Windows API. Start with [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242.aspx). It can wait for various types of kernel handles, including thread handles, but also notify you when messages are available. The idea is that you'll call that function in a loop. When it says messages are available, handle them, and then loop again to continue waiting.

The following is just an outline. You'll want to check the documentation for all the API functions used, and combine that with the rest of the knowledge you have about your own threads.

```
procedure TSecondaryThread.Execute;
var
  ret: DWord;
  ThreadHandle: THandle;
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  ThreadHandle := TertiaryThread.Handle;
  repeat
    ret := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, ThreadHandle, False, Infinite, qs_AllEvents);
    case ret of
      Wait_Object_0: begin
        // The thread terminated. Do something about it.
        CloseHandle(ThreadHandle);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        // Put *something* in the parameter so further calls to MWFMO
        // will have a valid handle. May as well use a handle to something
        // that will never become signaled so all we'll get are more
        // messages. I'm pretty sure you can't pass an empty array of
        // handles; there must be at least one, and it must be valid.
        ThreadHandle := Self.Handle;
      end;
      Wait_Object_0 + 1: begin
        // At least one message is available. Handle *all* of
        // them before calling MsgWaitForMultipleObjects again
        while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, pm_Remove) do
        case Msg.Message of
          wm_Quit: begin
            // Do something about terminating the tertiary thread.
            // Then stop the message loop and the waiting loop.
            Exit;
          end;
          else begin
            TranslateMessage(Msg);
            DispatchMessage(Msg);
          end;
        end;
      end;
      Wait_Timeout: Assert(False, 'Infinity has passed');
      Wait_Failed: RaiseLastOSError;
      else Assert(False, 'Unexpected return value');
    end;
  until False;
end;
```

The part about handling *all* the messages is important. As soon as you call `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`, or `WaitMessage`, the OS marks all messages in the queue as "old," but `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` will only return when there is a "new" message on the queue — one that arrived *after* the last call to `PeekMessage`.

Comment: +1 (more if I could) since few people understand threading well, and you are among the even fewer that can explain threading issues.

Comment: Agree with Jeroen. +1, Rob - nice job!

Answer (score 0):

HI, Thanks for your reply, yes i realize that my question isn't very clear and somewhat confusing; so i'll try to clarify things a bit, here goes..

All of the threads described below are derived from TThread.

I have a form which starts a thread but does not wait for it. The thread started by the form calls a function that performs a long task.

The function calls another function in a DLL, the function in the DLL starts a thread and waits for it.  The thread started by the DLL function calls another function via synchronize.

Form->Starts a thread but does not wait->The thread calls a functions->The function calls a DLL function->The Dll function starts a thread and waits->The thread started by the DLL function calls another function via synchronize i.e Synchronize(UpdateRecords).

The problem is that the call to synchronize never returns because, from what i can see, it has entered some sort of dead lock.

How synchronize works: Synchronize puts the method call into a queue and sets an event, Synchronize then waits for the event to become signaled.  When the main thread is idle it will process the method calls that are waiting in the queue, after it has processed a method call it will signal the associated event so that the thread that initiated the synchronization can continue on.

The thread that was started by the form does not use synchronize to call the function that performs the long task, if it does use synchronize then the application does not dead lock, but this defeats the purpose of use a thread for the long process.

I've tracked down the problem, it seems to be that the TApplication object created by the dll is not processing messages and has a handle of 0, how this happened I don't know (I didn't write the DLL, it was written by someone else), but it is a cause of the problem because it will never process the method called queued by synchronize.

I mentioned earlier that if i call the function that performs the long process from my thread using synchronize then the application does not dead lock.  This is because the main thread will be responsible for calling the function that performs the long process.  So the long process function calls a DLL function which starts another thread and then calls WaitFor.  WaitFor checks to see if the current thread is the main thread, and if it is, it processes method calls which have been queued by synchronize, continuously in a loop until the thread the thread that it is waiting for is released (i.e. the method it queued via synchronize gets called and the wait event is signaled).

In WaitFor, if the current thread is not the main thread then WaitFor simply blocks until the thread it is waiting for is released.

Anyway i can't do anything about the application object in the dll because that dll is quite complex and used by a larger system. I guess i can expose a method in the dll which can process the methods in the synchronization queue, i can then call this method from my application while its idle.

Anyway again thanks for your help but i've solved this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `TThread` class or even the `Application` object in a Delphi DLL is *extremely* unsafe. The RTL and VCL core classes, globals and singleton objects are designed to exist once per process and can't handle the namespace duplication and incomplete initialization in a stadard DLL library.
You may get around it by building with runtime packages (RTL & VCL are enough; you may also build your own with just the system units you reallt need), in the EXE and all DLLs referencing the runtime units (Forms and Classes, especially) - they get single shared namespace and the full EXE initialization sequence this way.
If you can't modify the DLL at all, you may try to set it's `Application.Handle`, `MainThreadID`, `SyncEvent` and `WakeMainThread` to the corresponding values in the main EXE module - this *may* work, but it's just as ugly as it looks like and it doesn't cover all edge-cases (the classes and important globals will still be duplicated).